# Azure login Error at work - Getting Error fetching tenants message - proxy settings?

Tags: azure, authentication

When i login to portal.azure.com from my work network , i get the following error message in the notification

**'Error fetching tenants'
'There was an error fetching tenants. Please reload the portal to try again.'**

The portal does list the resource's e.g. storage. However on clicking any, it show 'Unexpected error'

Additional Details on the error:
On F12, i see the following calls failed
https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2015-11-01
https://s2.billing.ext.azure.com/api/Billing/RemainingCredits

I tried with chrome, Internet explorer and fire-fox
Do i need to request admin's to grant any specific access?

I have a 'Visual Studio Professional Subscription'. if i login from home pc, it works. Kindoff limiting exploring azure for work

I am not sure why all other azure posted from azure portal work except a few key once

Comment: From home are you using your work account or a different one? Did you try it from an Incognito browser?  Is it automatically logging you in or do you type your user name and password?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, and the root cause was geoblocking at firewall.  If you have things locked down to, say, just the United States, the Azure portal and certain applications within may not always function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, searched endlessly for answers.

Ended up clearing all cache and cookies, the error message has since gone and I can use the Azure Portal again.

Accessing Azure on MacOS Ventura Version 13.4 through Safari 16.5.